# Iphone viewport and scalable images

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios

I have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

So the user doesn't need to zoom, but I have an image which is `417x47` and it looks too big, I mean the user has to scroll left and right in order to see it.If I remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />` It looks how I want, but I can't do this since I have a lot of text content, Is there a way to scale down only the images, or what's the size that I will need to resize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query to set the width of the images to 100%, or a pixel-size you think its right, like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the design is only for iphone, using wp touch but the main thing is that the image that i'm trying to scale down is the logo...I guess the only option is to cut it down to about 200x20 or something

Comment: @Uffo you can do the same for the logo image, just specify the class that its using and the width desired for your mobile devices and it should work just fine.